# asp.net web forms threading in a request handling

Tags: asp.net, webforms

If I start a thread from request handling in code behind in asp.net web forms and request is handled faster than the thread finishes - will it be aborted or allowed to run further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread should be completely separate from the request thread at this point, so will continue working.

Comment: do you have any good references about threading in asp.net mvc3 or webforms?

Comment: @IamStalker - Threading is the same as it would be in other environments. A thread is a thread.